# Is it possible to use VBA code for using the index and match command on a filtered table?

Tags: excel, vba

I already have a table filtered out. Just wanted to know if this was even possible.

I already have this code written out just for reference.

```
                 Dim WorkOrderDeliverableDatelastRow As Long
                 WorkOrderDeliverableDatelastRow = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                 
                 Dim DeliverableDatelastRow As Long
                 DeliverableDatelastRow = .Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                 
                                          
                  Set WorkOrderRange = .Range("E2:E" & WorkOrderDeliverableDatelastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                  
                  
                  
                  Set DeliverableDateRange = .Range("K2:K" & DeliverableDatelastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                  
                  
                workOrder = Application.Index(WorkOrderRange, Application.Match(cel.Value, DeliverableDateRange, 0))
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to your previous question, I don't think so. You could loop though. Maybe `Range.Find` too but untested.

Comment: I am sure it doesn't. It searches/considers from the discontinuous range only the first area. If it happens that the searched string to be in this first area it is returned.

Comment: `Find` (on the whole column range) will not find hidden cells if you specify `lookIn:=xlValues`, but will find hidden cells if you use `lookIn:=xlFormulas`